# Can LINQ expression use LEFT JOIN or default to null if item isn't found?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to track down a crash in some existing code in a web app I inherited..  I've traced this down to a single LINQ expression:

```
var projInfo = (from v in context.TPM_PROJECTVERSION
                join p in context.TPM_PROJECT on v.PROJECTID equals p.PROJECTID
                join pto in context.TPM_USER on v.TPM_USER1.USERID equals pto.USERID
                join pt in context.TPM_PROJECTTYPES on p.PROJECTTYPEID equals pt.PROJECTTYPEID
                where v.PROJECTID == projectId && v.VERSIONID == versionId
                select new
                {
                    ProjectName = v.NAME,
                    ProjectType = pt.SHORTNAME,
                    ProjectDesc = v.DESCRIPTION,
                    BusinessLaunchData = p.BUSINESSLAUNCHDATE,
                    BusinessSponsor = (v.TPM_USER3.FIRSTNAME + " " + v.TPM_USER3.LASTNAME),
                    PrimaryTrainingOwner = (pto.FIRSTNAME + " " + pto.LASTNAME)
                }).First();
```

The error is "Sequence contains no elements", which I've traced to this line:

```
join pto in context.TPM_USER on v.TPM_USER1.USERID equals pto.USERID
```

If USER1 is null, the row does not get returned.  Instead, I need PrimaryTrainingOwner to just be null or blank instead.  Basically, I need to do a LEFT JOIN instead and check for this while setting PrimaryTrainerOwner.  Is there a way to update this LINQ expression to handle this case?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution.  I'd appreciate any comments on whether this is the best approach or syntax or whatever.  Thanks!

```
var projInfo = (from v in context.TPM_PROJECTVERSION
                join p in context.TPM_PROJECT on v.PROJECTID equals p.PROJECTID
                join pto in context.TPM_USER on v.TPM_USER1.USERID equals pto.USERID into primaryowner
                from subpto in primaryowner.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join pt in context.TPM_PROJECTTYPES on p.PROJECTTYPEID equals pt.PROJECTTYPEID
                where v.PROJECTID == projectId && v.VERSIONID == versionId
                select new
                {
                    ProjectName = v.NAME,
                    ProjectType = pt.SHORTNAME,
                    ProjectDesc = v.DESCRIPTION,
                    BusinessLaunchData = p.BUSINESSLAUNCHDATE,
                    BusinessSponsor = (v.TPM_USER3.FIRSTNAME + " " + v.TPM_USER3.LASTNAME),
                    PrimaryTrainingOwner = subpto == null ? String.Empty : (subpto.FIRSTNAME + " " + subpto.LASTNAME)
                }).First();
```

Comment: That's exactly right. You do have the option to reuse `pto` instead of `subpto`, since the original `pto` value is out of scope, if you think that would help readability.